# python regex to remove comments

Tags: python, regex

How would I write a regex that removes all comments that start with the # and stop at the end of the line -- but at the same time exclude the first two lines which say

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

and

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Comments don't slow your code down. Why do you want to remove them?

Comment: You don't :). At least, not with a simple regex. Consider the following: `s = 'not # a # comment!'`, or this: `s = """ \n foo # \n bar """` (where `\n` are actual line breaks)

Comment: @agf, to make things more difficult for the next person to work on the code!

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/1621521 , where there is already a (not entirely regex) solution that may satisfy your needs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove comments by parsing the Python code with `tokenize.generate_tokens`. The following is a slightly modified version of [this example from the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/tokenize.html#tokenize.untokenize):

```
import tokenize
import io
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    StringIO = io.StringIO
else:
    StringIO = io.BytesIO

def nocomment(s):
    result = []
    g = tokenize.generate_tokens(StringIO(s).readline)  
    for toknum, tokval, _, _, _  in g:
        # print(toknum,tokval)
        if toknum != tokenize.COMMENT:
            result.append((toknum, tokval))
    return tokenize.untokenize(result)

with open('script.py','r') as f:
    content=f.read()

print(nocomment(content))
```

For example:

If script.py contains

```
def foo(): # Remove this comment
    ''' But do not remove this #1 docstring 
    '''
    # Another comment
    pass
```

then the output of `nocomment` is

```
def foo ():
    ''' But do not remove this #1 docstring 
    '''

    pass
```

Comment: I'm just curious: How well does this handle stuff like extra whitespace?

Comment: @PiPeep: For an example of how tokenize can handle whitespace, see [reindent.py](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Tools/scripts/reindent.py).

Comment: i think your code need updation, which is now giving error, `File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 565, in _tokenize
    if line[pos] in '#\r\n':           # skip comments or blank lines
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int`  in the library itself

Comment: your code works in python 2.7, but not in python 3.6

Comment: Updated for Python3.

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually think this can be done purely with a regex expression, as you'd need to count quotes to ensure that an instance of `#` isn't inside of a string.

I'd look into [python's built-in code parsing modules](http://docs.python.org/library/language.html) for help with something like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e '1,2p' -e '/^\s*#/d' infile
```

Then wrap this in a [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) call.

However, this *doesn't* substitute a real parser! Why would this be of interest? Well, assume this Python script:

```
output = """
This is
#1 of 100"""
```

Boom, any non-parsing solution instantly breaks your script.

Comment: Why not just use the python `re` package in the example, rather than requiring a platform-dependent tool?