# Extracting comments from Python Source Code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a program to extract comments in code that user enters. I tried to use regex, but found it difficult to write.

Then I found a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032031/python-regex-to-remove-comments). The answer suggests to use `tokenize.generate_tokens` to analyze the grammar, but [the documentation says](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/tokenize.html#tokenize.generate_tokens):

> The `generate_tokens()` generator requires one argument, `readline`, which
>   must be a callable object which provides the same interface as the
>   `readline()` method of built-in file objects (see section File Objects).

But a string object does not have `readline` method.

Then I found another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472839/python-readline-from-a-string), suggesting to use `StringIO.StringIO` to get a `readline` method. So I wrote the following code:

```
import tokenize
import io
import StringIO

def extract(code):
    res = []
    comment = None
    stringio = StringIO.StringIO(code)
    for toktype, tokval, begin, end, line in tokenize.generate_tokens(stringio):
        # print(toknum,tokval)
        if toktype != tokenize.COMMENT:
            res.append((toktype, tokval))
        else:
            print tokenize.untokenize(toktype)
    return tokenize.untokenize(res)
```

And entered the following code: `extract('a = 1+2#A Comment')`

But got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):     
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>     
   File "ext.py", line 10, in extract     
     for toktype, tokval, begin, end, line in tokenize.generate_tokens(stringio):     
   File "C:\Python27\lib\tokenize.py", line 294, in generate_tokens     
     line = readline()     
AttributeError: StringIO instance has no `__call__` method
```

I know I can write a new class, but is there any better solution?

Comment: Show us the code that gave you that AttributeError.

Comment: You're onto the right solution. Please show some code so we can help you make it work.

Comment: for Python3:: from io import StringIO

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Answer for more general cases (extracting from modules, functions):

#### Modules:

The documentation specifies that one needs to provide a callable which exposes the same interface as the **[`readline()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline)** method of built-in **file** objects. This hints to: create an object that provides that method.

In the case of module, we can just **[`open`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open)** a new module as a normal file and pass in it's `readline` method.
This is the key, *the argument you pass **is** the method `readline()`*.

Given a small `scrpt.py` file with:

```
# My amazing foo function.
def foo():
    """ docstring """
    # I will print
    print "Hello"
    return 0   # Return the value

# Maaaaaaain
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # this is main
    print "Main"
```

We will open it as we do all files:

```
fileObj = open('scrpt.py', 'r')
```

This file object now has a method called `readline` (because it is a file object) which we can safely pass to `tokenize.generate_tokens` and create a generator.

**[`tokenize.generate_tokens`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/tokenize.html#tokenize.generate_tokens)** (simply [**`tokenize.tokenize`**](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tokenize.html#tokenize.tokenize) in Py3 -- **Note:** Python 3 requires readline return `bytes` so you'll need to open the file in `'rb'` mode) returns a named tuple of elements which contain information about the elements tokenized. Here's a small demo:

```
for toktype, tok, start, end, line in tokenize.generate_tokens(fileObj.readline):
    # we can also use token.tok_name[toktype] instead of 'COMMENT'
    # from the token module 
    if toktype == tokenize.COMMENT:
        print 'COMMENT' + " " + tok
```

Notice how we pass the `fileObj.readline` method to it. This will now print:

```
COMMENT # My amazing foo function
COMMENT # I will print
COMMENT # Return the value
COMMENT # Maaaaaaain
COMMENT # this is main
```

So all comments regardless of position are detected. Docstrings of course are excluded.

#### Functions:

You could achieve a similar result without `open` for cases which I really can't think of. Nonetheless, I'll present another way of doing it for completeness sake. In this scenario you'll need two additional modules, **[`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/inspect.html)** and **[`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stringio.html#module-StringIO)** (**[`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/io.html#io.StringIO)** in `Python3`):

Let's say you have the following function:

```
def bar():
    # I am bar
    print "I really am bar"
    # bar bar bar baaaar
    # (bar)
    return "Bar"
```

You need a file-like object which has a `readline` method to use it with `tokenize`. Well, you can create a file-like object from an `str` using `StringIO.StringIO` and you can get an `str` representing the source of the function with [`inspect.getsource(func)`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource). In code:

```
funcText = inpsect.getsource(bar)
funcFile = StringIO.StringIO(funcText)
```

Now we have a file-like object representing the function which has the wanted `readline` method. We can just re-use the loop we previously performed replacing `fileObj.readline` with `funcFile.readline`. The output we get now is of similar nature:

```
COMMENT # I am bar
COMMENT # bar bar bar baaaar
COMMENT # (bar)
```

---

As an aside, if you really want to create a custom way of doing this with `re` take a look at [the source for the `tokenize.py` module](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/tokenize.py). It defines certain patters for comments, (`r'#[^\r\n]*'`) names et cetera, loops through the lines with `readline` and searches within the `line` list for pattterns. Thankfully, it's not too complex after you look at it for a while :-).

---

#### Answer for function `extract` (Update):

You've created an object with `StringIO` that provides the interface but *have you haven't passed that intereface (`readline`) to `tokenize.generate_tokens`, instead, you passed the full object (`stringio`)*.

Additionally, in your `else` clause a `TypeError` is going to be raised because `untokenize` expects an iterable as input. Making the following changes, your function works fine:

```
def extract(code):
    res = []
    comment = None
    stringio = StringIO.StringIO(code)
    # pass in stringio.readline to generate_tokens
    for toktype, tokval, begin, end, line in tokenize.generate_tokens(stringio.readline):
        if toktype != tokenize.COMMENT:
            res.append((toktype, tokval))
        else:
            # wrap (toktype, tokval) tupple in list
            print tokenize.untokenize([(toktype, tokval)])
    return tokenize.untokenize(res)
```

Supplied with input of the form `expr = extract('a=1+2#A comment')` the function will print out the comment and retain the expression in `expr`:

```
expr = extract('a=1+2#A comment')
#A comment

print expr
'a =1 +2 '
```

Furthermore, as I later mention `io` houses `StringIO` for Python3 so in this case the `import` is thankfully not required.

Comment: (python 3.6)Passing the fileObject.readline directly to tokenize.tokenize will only work if it is opened in mode 'rb' since I guess tokenize expects bytestring from readline().

Comment: @philoj it does. Apparently in all Python > 3 versions. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

Use this Third-Party Library from PyPI

[Comment Parser](https://pypi.org/project/comment-parser/)